# Esri Javascript API .applyEdits() firing on("edits-complete"), not erroring, but not updating the database

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This is a log of my troubleshooting chat in The Spatial Community Slack. I thought it could be helpful to memorialize it once the 10,000 message monster eats it.

I'm struggling to get `featureLayer.applyEdits()` working

It's hitting the callback, but not firing `on('edits-complete')`

it's silently doing nothing

after hitting submit, the data doesn't update

here's where it's called:
`RRWCFeatureLayer.applyEdits(null, feature, null, clearForm, errback)`

the `feature` object is a `graphic` returned by a `queryTask`, appended with `attribute` information typed into the page. It's currently a hosted feature service for dev. Eventually it'll point to a Server service.

davetimmins: the edits expects an array so try `RRWCFeatureLayer.applyEdits(null, [feature], null, clearForm, errback)`

changing it to `[feature]` allowed the `on("edits-complete")` to fire... but the data doesn't actually change in the database

so when I look at an example with `.applyEdits()` passes back an object that is similar but not identical to the object I'm using

From Esri’s attribute inspector example

[image: esris examples]

My object

[image: my object]

the docs just say it needs a valid `objectid`

i'm modifying the object returned by a `QueryTask`

does my object not contain the necessary properties to be a proper `Graphic`?

do I need to run `feature.setAttributes()` rather than just setting the properties directly using `feature.attributes.<field> = "value"`?

jmfolds: I ran into something similar to this recently. I feel like I ended up querying the featureLayer directly for the graphic. It *seemed* like the graphic passed to featureLayer.applyEdits to update had to exist in the featureLayer.graphics array or something? I could also be completely wrong.

oh and i just tested using `setAttributes()` and the layer still isn't updating. It replaces all the attributes with ones that I set.

davetimmins: use this graphic `var graphic = new Graphic(results.features[0].geometry, symbol)`, set the attributes for that too and then pass that to the applyEdits

jmfolds: ah ddavetimmins I didn't notice that. themapsmith I think if you use `feature = new Graphic(results.features[0].geometry, symbol, results.features[0].attributes)` that should work?

That got my graphic down into my submit code but it’s still not updating the data.

Digging into the NCAA update example, i'm noticing some other subtle differences

the `UpdateFeatures` object being submitted has `_count:2` and `_cache: null` properties, otherwise the top level properties are the same

When i look at the network request, my `feature` JSON looks like this:

```
    [
       {
          "geometry":{
             "x":-73.24948728213145,
             "y":44.181510999714426,
             "spatialReference":{
                "wkid":4326,
                "latestWkid":4326
             }
          },
          "attributes":{
             "OBJECTID":1300,
             "AppDate":1467345600000,
             "CompName":"Engineers Construction, Inc.",
             "WorkReason":"Yes",
             "BillAddress":"1 National Life Dr",
             "BillTown":"Montpelier",
             "BillState":"VT",
             "BillZIP":"05604",
             "CompType":"Private",
             "AppName":"Stephen Smith",
             "AppPhone":"802-828-5379",
             "AppEmail":null,
             "WorkRR":"VTRN",
             "WorkTown":"Vergennes",
             "WorkFromMP":94,
             "WorkToMP":null,
             "WorkDuration":"3 hours",
             "WorkStartDate":1469073600000,
             "WorkDescription":"I need to go and fix a thing about the stuff because I need to have a long description text just in case somebody gets a little long winded",
             "WorkEquipment":"Excavator",
             "WorkCompletionDate":1469073600000,
             "WorkAsset":"Rail",
             "RPMApprovalBy":"Kevin Clairmont",
             "RPMComment":"dddddddddddddddddddd",
             "RPMDecisionDate":"9/01/16",
             "RRDecision":"approved"
          },
          "symbol":{
             "color":[
                20,
                175,
                200,
                150
             ],
             "size":17,
             "angle":0,
             "xoffset":0,
             "yoffset":0,
             "type":"esriSMS",
             "style":"esriSMSDiamond",
             "outline":{
                "color":[
                   255,
                   255,
                   255,
                   255
                ],
                "width":1,
                "type":"esriSLS",
                "style":"esriSLSSolid"
             }
          }
       }
    ]
```

However, the NCAA example JSON looks like this:

```
    [  
       {  
          "attributes":{  
             "University":"Northern Iowa",
             "WINPER":1088904,
             "Rd_64_Venue":"Quicken Loans Arena",
             "Rd_64_Result":"R",
             "Rd_64_Margin":320,
             "OBJECTID":71
          }
       }
    ]
```

Why isn't my feature layer being updated by the `.applyEdits()` request?

ok another difference in the code from the NCAA example:
the example object is `updateFeature = features[0]` from a `featureLayer.selectFeatures` query, then the `applyEdits` is called like this:
`updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, [updateFeature], null)`
whereas my `feature` object is the `results.features[0]` from a `QueryTask`, with attributes updated. it is called like
`featureLayer.applyEdits(null, [feature], null, callback, errback)`
the `results` is passed to a new `Graphic` like so:
`feature = new Graphic(results.features[0].geometry, symbol, results.features[0].attributes)`

Comment: I had a problem once with `applyEdits` not working, but not erroring out either. Turned out to be a datatype mismatch where my `applyEdits` call was sending a string date to a field that was expecting a `date` type. Took lots of digging through the network traffic to figure that one out.

Answer (score 2):

**Outcome:**

It turns out, by capturing data in a plain HTML form, I wasn’t honoring the field settings of the feature class. When sending invalid data into a field, the REST API returns an object reporting on the outcome.
Here’s the response:

```
    {
       "addResults":[

       ],
       "updateResults":[
          {
             "objectId":1300,
             "globalId":null,
             "success":false,
             "error":{
                "code":1000,
                "description":"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Mark Fitzgerald' to data type int."
             }
          }
       ],
       "deleteResults":[

       ]
    }
```

The above error code is not caught in a `try/catch`, nor reported in the `errback`

From rene: use `layer.applyEdits().then().otherwise()`. technically it didn’t error out, it failed. that’s different. that’s why the `success` property is sent.
That may be some internal workings of the FeatureLayer, I’m not sure. the REST API don’t care (see Apply Edits Feature Service Layer in REST API docs)
The results of the applyEdits will not return as an error to be caught because not everything may in the applyEdits may fail. Some adds/updates/deletes may be fine, when others may fail for some reason
That’s why the success property, error and codes and sent back
the errback and otherwise for Deferred error catcher will only kick in if there is an issue connecting wth the service
try/catch only works for unhandled exceptions, but not for unhandled Promise errors

**The lesson:**
Validate your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with graphics returned by QueryTask. I was altering the path of the graphics and was trying to save it. While saving it was throwing error. 
I replace the QueryTask with selectFeatures and it worked in my case. Try using selectFreatures.

Comment: Thanks @anurodh. That suggestion was made to me, and I would have probably switched to s selectFeatures if I hadn't managed to get the update working via QueryTask. Glad you got it to work